# How to target domain root in a Firebase hosting header rule

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have a web app using custom domain. This domain has A record mapped to 151.101.1.195 and 151.101.65.195.

Everything works correctly, but when I have firebase.json like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "headers": [{
      "source": "**/*.html",
      "headers": [{
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "private, max-age=0, no-cache"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

I still see the response headers like this when I visit https://mycustomdomain.com:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:max-age=3600
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:839
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Wed, 27 Sep 2017 06:54:58 GMT
etag:"f0b36e6c2a348eb46d07907fea856e9a"
last-modified:Wed, 27 Sep 2017 06:53:07 GMT
server:nginx
status:200
strict-transport-security:max-age=31556926
vary:Accept-Encoding
via:1.1 varnish
x-cache:HIT
x-cache-hits:2
x-powered-by:Express
x-served-by:cache-bma7024-BMA
x-timer:S1506495298.256593,VS0,VE0
```

I expect the cache control header to be modified, but it doesn't change.

How can I change the response headers for domain root?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking, I ended up doing it like this, and it seems to work:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "private, max-age=0, no-cache"
        }]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "private, max-age=0, no-cache"
        }]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.js",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=31536000"
        }]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.css",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=31536000"
        }]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.jpg",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=31536000"
        }]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.png",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=31536000"
        }]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        { "source": "/api/1/mina", "function": "mydata" },
        { "source": "**", "destination": "/index.html" } 
      ]
  }
}
```

This also works with functions. Note that .js files are also agressively cached, as we use cache busting urls.

Comment: You could minify your JSON by merging assets rules: Instead of `"source": "**/*.png"`, `"source": "**/*.css"`, etc. try `"source": "**/*@(js|css|jpg|png)"`